# Error when trying to encode text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’ve been trying to correct this text for the standard view for hours. I tried several ways for utf-8 and nothing works. can anybody help me?
I believe it is not a duplicate question because I have tried everything and failed.
Here is an example of one of the codes I used:

```
string_old = u"\u00c2\u00bfQu\u00c3\u00a9 le pasar\u00c3\u00a1 a quien desobedezca los mandamientos? "
print(string_old.encode("utf-8"))
```

Result:

```
>>> b'\xc3\x82\xc2\xbfQu\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9 le pasar\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1 a quien desobedezca los mandamientos? '
```

I expect the following result:

```
>>> "¿Qué le pasará a quien desobedezca los mandamientos? "
```

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Comment: What's the problem? The result looks exactly as it should to me.

Comment: Is there an “error” message - if so edit the full text into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string was wrongly decoded as Latin1 (or cp1252):

```
string_old.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
# '¿Qué le pasará a quien desobedezca los mandamientos? '
```

Comment: I've been trying for hours. This result came from the API of the company I work for. Worked perfectly. Thank you!